# Multiply Total by 12 - js - use currency format

Tags: javascript, calculator, multiplication

I am trying to multiply a result from a calculator by 12 to calculate an "annual" figure.

I am not sure how to write the function in a way that will maintain the decimal points:

HTML:

```
<p>Check Payments Per Month: <input type="text" class="hours"/></p>
<p>Cost per Payment: <input type="text" class="rate"/></p>
<input type="button" class="cbut" value="Calculate"/>
<p>Total Monthly Savings: $ <span class="total"></span></p>
<p>Total Annual Savings: $ <span class="totalyr"></span></p>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var $xhours = $('.hours');
var $xrate = $('.rate');
var $xcbut = $('.cbut');
var $xtotal = $('.total');
var $ytotal = $('.totalyr');

$xcbut.click(function()
{
    $xtotal.text(function()
    {
        var total = ($xhours.val() * $xrate.val());

        return total.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
    });

     $ytotal.text(function()
    {



    });


});
});
```

Working JS here: https://jsfiddle.net/j52zsc2b/16/

Comment: Just did it quick and dirty here: https://jsfiddle.net/j52zsc2b/19/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.ceil` as below:

```
// precision is 10 for 10ths, 100 for 100ths, etc.
function roundUp(num, precision) {
  return Math.ceil(num * precision) / precision
}

roundUp(192.168, 10) //=> 192.2
```

Comment: Do you need to round _up_?  Without "up", `Math.round(num, 1)` is simpler.